# Mount error on new, empty External HDD - ext4

Tags: mount, external-hdd, ext4

Apologies if this seems like a very similar question to others already on the site. I have searched for a few hours now for solutions, but nothing seems to be quite the same.

I recently (2 days ago) bought a new 4TB external HDD for data storage and have been trying to format it for linux (specifically Red Hat 5.9 and Ubuntu 12.04). I used the disk utility to format it to free space and then gparted to create a single ext4 primary partition. It loads fine on the Ubuntu system which I used to format the drive, however when connected to the Red Hat system it errors:

> Cannot mount volume.
>
> Unable to mount the volume 'jdru4706'.
>
> mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb1, missing codepage or other error In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try    dmesg | tail or so

Running dmesg | tail gives the following:

```
sdb: assuming drive cache: write through
SCSI device sdb: 976754646 4096-byte hdwr sectors (4000787 MB)
sdb: Write Protect is off
sdb: Mode Sense: 2b 00 10 08
sdb: assuming drive cache: write through
 sdb: sdb1
sd 16:0:0:0: Attached scsi disk sdb
sd 16:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
usb-storage: device scan complete
EXT4-fs (sdb1): bad geometry: block count 976754176 exceeds size of device (439883264 blocks)
```

I don't currently have any data on the drive so I can reformat if I need to. I don't understand what is causing this problem however. The only reason I wish to connect to the Red Hat system is to copy data files across for access on my laptop (the Ubuntu system).

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo mount -t ext4 /dev/sdb1 /<device_name>
```

If that doesn't help, and the drive has no data yet, delete the partition, and recreate it.  Hope that helps.